# The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user

Tags: community, reporting, permissions, dashboard, partner

I have configured partner community. There is opportunity pipeline report configure for Community user. But when I open up the report in partner community by logging with community user. Report says "You don’t have sufficient privileges to perform this operation."

But Report folder is shared with Community user, he can read opportunity object, have read access to all fields that report is associate with, OWD is Public Read/Write.

There is a dashboard component that used the above report and when I view that dashboard it says "The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user."

Do we need to provide any persimmons to standard report types?
Following profile permission are added for community user

Run Reports permisson granted.

If you guys have any idea why this happens please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks,
Wishwa

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue. Go to sharing settings with following steps Setup > Security > Sharing Settings then enable external Sharing. This will fix this issue.

Thanks,
Wishwa

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue (had reports shared with the correct users/groups/profile but we could still not view reports due to your error mentioned. Report and Dashboard permissions were also granted.

It ended up being the report type. Navigate to **Setup** > search "report" > **Report Types**. Make sure the report type you are using is ***Deployed*** and not *In Development*.

Sorry the answer is late but hopefully you've found a fix by now!

Courtney

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i noticed there was a legend "viewing as User X", and that was the user who created the Dashboard initially.

That user was inactivated as he was no longer working in this org.

The solution is edit the Dashboard, then change the settings to run the dashboard as "Me".

Adding this comment to have it documented in case somebody run in a similar issue.